# Match all characters except the last if it's a semicolon

Tags: python, regex

I'd like to perform a regexp search operation in python to match everything, but one character (which in this example is at the end):

```
expression = re.compile(r'http:\/\/.*')
```

The above regular expression would match whole url: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask;` and what I want to do is to get a match without the final `;` character.

Comment: Your wording is a bit ambiguous. Do you need to match "everything until a semicolon" or "everything except the last character (no matter what it is) in the input string"?

Comment: Everything except the last character if it's a semicolon :)

Comment: So basically: match everything until the last character of the input except when that last character is a semicolon, then match everything until the second-to-last character of the input?

Comment: I think "what I want to do is to get a match without the final ';' character" and "Everything except the last character if it's a semicolon" are the same.

Comment: Yes, but Rohit Jain's answer assumes that there are *no semicolons* before the last character of the input. His solution would match `http://foo` in `http://foo;bar`. If you need to match semicolons in the middle too, you'd need something like `http:\/\/.*(?=;?$)`. Of course, these are equivalent when the only possible place for a semicolon would be at the end of the input. Anyhow, if it works for you, it's fine for me. :-P

Comment: Late ninja edit: that regular expression should be `/http:\/\/(?:[^;]|;(?!$))*/`. It's quite a bit more complex with that lookahead, I know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a negated character class instead of `dot (.)` at the end: -

```
expression = re.compile(r'http:\/\/[^;]*')
```

Comment: @nienawiedzony.. Note that if you just want to match till the last character, then you would have to change the regex. The current regex will match till the first `;`.

Comment: Actually your answer satisfies me, because the last character would be a semicolon.